# В чем причина ошибки "invalid conversion"?

Tags: c++

Добрый день, с недавнего времени начал изучать C++ и столкнулся с такой проблемой: уже 3 примера подряд не могу понять; компилятор выводит ошибку в строке 29:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’

Вот сам код.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
///////////////////////////

int main()
{
    void order(int*, int*);
    int n1 = 99, n2 = 11;
    int n3 = 22, n4 = 88;
    order(&n1, &n2);
    order(&n3, &n4);
    cout << "n1 = " << n1 << endl;
    cout << "n2 = " << n2 << endl;
    cout << " n3 = " << n3 << endl;
    cout << " n4 = " << n4 << endl;
    return 0;
}
void order(int* numb1, int* numb2)
{
    if(*numb1 > *numb2)
    {
        int temp = *numb1;
        numb1 = numb2;
        numb2 =temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Естественно, вы присваиваете указателю значение. Должно быть так:

```
void order(int* numb1, int* numb2)
{
    if(*numb1 > *numb2)
    {
        int temp = *numb1;
        *numb1 = *numb2;
        *numb2 = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: gogolg, спасибо большое. В книге скорее всего опечатка.

Comment: Нажмите на галочку в кружке рядом с ответом, чтоб отметить его как правильный.